# Allow image form my domain only in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I customized the great filter in CKEditor to allow only some kind of tag:

```
config.allowedContent='img[!src]';
```

It works, but I also need to limit the src of the img to my domain only: I need something like this

```
config.allowedContent='img[!src=http://mysite.com/images/[1-9][0-9]*/dir/dir/file.jpg]';
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced Content Filter does not allow now to validate attributes/styles values. We decided not to implement this feature, because it would make the whole filter a lot more complex.  This may change in the future, but for now you can use a trick with the object format.

The object format of Allowed Content Rules is described very briefly in the [Allowed Content Rules guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-3) and you can check out the [example configuration](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/datafiltering.html) (3rd editor). But these samples do not show all object format's features. You'll be interested in the optional `match` property.

See [pagebreak plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/pagebreak/plugin.js#L129-L140) for the example. If `span` does not have `div` parent with a `page-break-after` style, then that rule won't be applied to the `span`, so if there's no other rule that will accept it, then it will be removed. So the `match` rule allow you to define to which elements this rule will be applied.

But note that this filter won't influence image dialog's behaviour (so much). So you should also modify the src input validator.

And one more thing - you need to allow `src=='cke-test'`, because this value is used to probe what filter allows. Without that image button may disappear.